# Android AChartEngine error

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using "achartengine", but I want to use `renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);` 
but its showing error:

```
The method setXRoundedLabels(boolean) is undefined for the type XYMultipleSeriesRenderer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setXRoundedLabels()` method is available starting with the 1.1.0 version of AChartEngine. You can download the 1.1.0-rc2 version [here](http://www.achartengine.org/download/).

Comment: please help me once more. i want points on Y axis as 0,0.5,1.0,1.5... instead of 0,1,2,3,4... what can i do

Answer (score 0):

As you are using achartengine library in your project,`renderer` is an object of `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` class which is defined in the library but it is not having any method named `setXRoundedLabels()` as per this document [achartengine reference doc](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html).

you can also see the class definition of `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` over [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/src/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.java?r=353)

Comment: please help me for this. i want points on Y axis as 0,0.5,1.0,1.5... instead of 0,1,2,3,4... what can i do

Comment: kindly post the name of chart in which you want to manipulate,or post the code.

Comment: ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(TidalChartActivity.this, buildDateDataset(titles, dates, values),
                   renderer, "yyyy-MM-dd \n hh:mm");

Comment: bro,I'm asking the name of Chart which is used in library,not the name of your TidalChartActivity.

Comment: time chart with XYMultipleSeriesRenderer .